# spring boot using websphere 8.5.5.5 JTA

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-boot, websphere, jta

I am success to deploy my spring project to websphere and try to run jersey call.
Unfortunately, it flow exception while in the @transactional call.

> Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: UOWManager transaction processing failed; nested exception is com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWException: java.lang.LinkageError: com/ibm/websphere/uow/UOWSynchronizationRegistry.registerInterposedSynchronization(Ljavax/transaction/Synchronization;)V

it seems that spring boot does not connect websphere JTA well. I would like to know how can I fix this issue, seems websphere api just descript the spring way setup but not the spring boot way. [websphere JTA guide](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cspr_data_access_tran1.html)

Comment: Check if you have accidentally included the JTA API jar in your deployment package and remove it. If you use Maven, set the scope for the API jar to provided.

Comment: It seems the same problem. I fixed it after exclude the JTA API in maven. Thanks

Comment: @travistam : Can you please post the fix as an answer, so that it may help those who are looking for a solution.